# android java threads running one after another but wait for each to complete before running next

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm struggling with threads and thread blocking.

I have an android activity that has 4 threads that will run in it.  These threads need to run without getting the ANR error and they also have to run one after the other so the first thread runs then only when it completes does the second thread start to run etc.  All the threads are running different code and the action has to loop round a set amount of times.  I have done an example of my problem below.  Don't get hung up on why they have to be done in threads they just do because of how the code runs, also its the whole issue of how to do the thread locking that I'm interested in.  The questions take a lot of computation to come up with and so does the checking of the answer.

Also need to know how to stop the thread running completely if the back or home button is pressed while the thread is running.

i.e.

Number of questions is how many times the process loops.

first thread
count down timer 3 2 1 before first question is shown.  Using count down timer for this so can wait for the onFinnish() before it goes onto next thread

second thread in an implement runnable
display the question to player

third thread in an implement runnable
player answers the question

forth thread this will be a count down timer again
show the result i.e. wether the player answered correctly.

Many help with this in advance.

Cheers

Comment: I dont have any code I'm still in the planning implementation stage :S